# How to pass flags to the preprocessor during Conditional Assembly

Tags: gcc, gnu-assembler, c-preprocessor

I want to pass certain macros defined in Makefile to preprocessor like "_DBGR_ON_" in the following code so that code will be assembled accordingly. This option is working in diab compiler(c cross compiler for powerpc) by defining it with -D_DBGR_ON_ in makefile and including it as Assembler flag. 
But how to include it in GCC.

When I do the same(ASFLAGS = -mregnames -D_DBGR_ON_.), i was getting error: unrecognized option `-_DBGR_ON_'

Then, I tried ASFLAGS = -mregnames -D _DBGR_ON_, I was getting "can't open _DBGR_ON_ for reading: No such file or directory"

Please help as -D option is ignored in GCC.

I was using -D option to  do **conditional assembly**, **compiling** in Diab. How to do it in GCC. I am stuck here.

Regards,
Thulasi

Contents of startup.s file...

```
    .globl      _start
_start:
.ifndef _DBGR_ON_   # Flash mode   
   mfmsr        r3
   ori        r3,r3,0x1040              # Set ME/IP flags
   mtmsr        r3
   sync
.else  
   mfmsr        r3
   ori        r3,r3,0x1000                # Set ME/IP flags
   mtmsr        r3
   sync
.endif #_DBGR_ON_
```

.......and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a `gas` issue than GCC or C preprocessor.  `gas` does not do preprocessing itself (although it can be run via `gcc` to invoke the C preprocessor first).  `.ifndef` is a `gas` directive which works at the level of symbols defined in the assembler file - not a C preprocessor directive (`#ifndef`).

In which case: what you need in your `ASFLAGS` is `--defsym _DBGR_ON_=1`.